# Layout Map Never Renders then Hangs if Map is Deleted

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, layouts

I have three layouts that are associated with my *.qgs project file.  Each layout includes at least one map and a number of text boxes that serve as captions for the map(s).

After a few days of formatting, my layouts are almost completely finished.  However, some of the maps on two of my layouts no longer display as I edit the layout (instead displaying "Rendering map" on a completely grey background).  For earlier versions of QGIS, the problem may have been that I toggled "Cache" or "Rectangle" instead of "Render," but these options do not display in this verions of QGIS (Girona, QGIS 3.0).

Importantly, if I try to delete any of the offending maps, QGIS hangs and I have to force quit or kill the program.  Also, I should mention that the offending maps successfully render when I export the layout to a pdf... I just can't see them while I'm editing the layouts.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: I upgraded to QGIS 3.8 (Zanznibar), and haven't had the problem since.

Comment: Are there any similarities between the maps that fail to render, that differentiate them from the maps that do render? If you make a copy of one of the maps, does the copy also fail to render? What if you duplicate the entire layout?

Comment: It sounds like you've encountered a bug. Try to figure out as much as you can about the scope and circumstances of the issue, then make a bug report. https://issues.qgis.org/issues

Comment: And if you haven't done so, make a backup copy of your project.

Comment: Interesting; csk's suggestion to create a duplicate layout appears to have worked.  The duplicate contains the maps, fully rendered.  Thanks!  I'll check back in if I can reproduce this solution on another project file.

Comment: This is strange. I have the same problem in QGIS 3.4 LTR. When I create a print layout with a script in the console, everything works fine. I embedded mentioned script into a processing script in the tool box. When run, the print layout is created as intended but the map doesn't render. When I create a duplicate of the faulty layout, it works. Have you found out more about this problem, yet?

Comment: Same problem here, but with GIS 3.10 LTR. However, the work around with the duplicated does not work.